# PHP mySQL display an array field into a while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have in my table, a field 'windows' witch is an integer. I want to convert this integer into an array of numbers. ex: 3-> 1,2,3; 5->1,2,3,4,5 and display this with the table.
So, I have a table :

```
| id | windows |
| 1  | 3       |
| 2  | 5       |

$stmt = $dbc->prepare("SELECT id, windows FROM table1");
$stmt -> execute();
while($row = $stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$id      = $row['id'];
$windows    = $row['windows'];

     $i=0;  
     for($i=1; $i <= $windows; $i++ ) {     
         $wi .= 'Win '. $i .'<br>'; 
     }

$display .= '<div>'. $wi .'</div>';
}
```

Now, ex.if in the first row windows = 3 ; in the second row windows = 5 ; will display :
1st row:
Win1
Win2
Win3

2nd row:
Win1
Win2
Win3
Win1
Win2
Win3
Win4
Win5.
   This is when i put .= (dot equal) after '$wi' and '$display'. If I put only = (equal), it's show me only the last value of each field ex. 3 and 5. What can I do to display only the array for each row? I've tried with 'foreach'

```
$i=0;   
for($i=1; $i<= $windows; $i++ ) {
    $j = explode(",", $i);
    foreach($j as $value){
    $wi .= 'Win '. $value .'<br>';
}
}
```

but give me the same result.
I want to display: 
ROW 1:
 Win1
Win2
Win3
ROW 2
Win1
Win2
Win3
Win4
Win5.
 Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show what your table looks like along with some sample data from that table and the desired output.

Comment: put full fragment of code that brings you a problem. don't put `.....` so that could be any code we never know.

Comment: Do you forgot to reset $wi variable? I mean, make $wi = ""; anywhere before the for loop.

Comment: THANK YOU Alexander Ravikovich !!!!!! That was the problem. Thanks!